# $Hom \left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i,\bigoplus_{j=1}^m N_j \right) \cong \bigoplus_{i,j}Hom(M_i,N_j)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $\{M_i\}_{i=1}^n$ y $\{N_j\}_{j=1}^m$ two families of $R$-modules. Show that $$Hom_R \left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i,\bigoplus_{j=1}^m N_j \right) \cong \bigoplus_{i,j}Hom_R(M_i,N_j)$$
Dem: Let $\varphi \in \bigoplus_{i,j}Hom_R(M_i,N_i)$, then $\varphi=(\varphi_{i,j})$, where $\varphi_{i,j}:M_i \rightarrow N_j$, $1\leq i \leq n$ y $1 \leq j \leq m $ we can consider the matrix with entries $\varphi_{i,j}$, and an element $x:=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, with $x_i \in M_i$, tal que:

\begin{matrix}
\varphi(x)= & \begin{pmatrix}
   \varphi_{11} &\cdots  & \varphi_{n1}\\
   \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots\\
   \varphi_{1m} & \cdots & \varphi_{nm} 
\end{pmatrix} &\begin{pmatrix}
    x_1\\
    \vdots\\
    x_n
\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}
    \sum_{i=1}^n \varphi_{i1}(x_i)\\
    \vdots\\
    \sum_{i=1}^n \varphi_{im}(x_i)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}

Then we define a $R$-homomorphism of modules  $\psi : \oplus
_{i,j} Hom_R(M_i,N_j) \rightarrow Hom_R(\oplus_i M_i, \oplus_j N_j)$

\begin{matrix}\psi((\varphi_{i,j})+(\tau_{i,j}))(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n (\varphi_{i1}+\tau_{i1})(x_i)\\
    \vdots\\
    \sum_{i=1}^n (\varphi_{im}+\tau_{im})(x_i)
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
  \sum_{i=1}^n \varphi_{i1}(x_i)\\
    \vdots\\
    \sum_{i=1}^n \varphi_{im}(x_i)  
\end{pmatrix} +  \begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n \tau_{i1}(x_i)\\
    \vdots\\
    \sum_{i=1}^n \tau_{im}(x_i)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}

I think this is the "natural" homomorphism, but I'm struggling to prove that is a biyection. Or to see the inverse to compose the identity, any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you already proved it. Just in case saying here in my answer,

Note that, $n \in \oplus_i N_i$ can be uniquely written as $n = \sum_i n_i$, $n_i 
 \in N_i$.

Take $\phi \in Hom(\oplus_i M_i, \oplus_i N_i)$, then for $m_j \in M_j$,

$\phi(m_j) \in \oplus_i N_i$ hence can be uniquely defined as $\phi(m_j) = \sum_i n_i$.

This uniquely gives a map $\phi_{ji}$ for every fixed $j$ defined as $\phi_{ji}(m_j) = n_i$. Since the map defined is unique, this is an injection between $Hom(\oplus_i M_i,\oplus_i N_i)$ into $\oplus_{ij} Hom(M_i,N_j)$.

Surjection can be proved by taking any maps $\psi_{ij}$ from $\oplus_{ij} Hom(M_i,N_j)$ and extending it to $Hom(\oplus_i M_i,\oplus_i N_i)$ by defining $\psi(m_j) = \sum_{ji} \psi_{ji}(m_j) $.

Comment: Thanks, it was the uniqueness I was not taking in count!